# COmparing time and timestamp fields in DB2

Tags: db2

How can I compare a time field and a timestamp field assuming I want to know if the time section of the timestamp is the same as what is stored in the time field?

Example:    Timestamp field is "Sun, 29 Nov 2015 03:13:01 GMT" and the Time field has 18:30. I want to do something like this

if TimeStampFieldTime = TimeField do Blah...

Thank you

Comment: By the article @ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html it looks like you should get away with casting timestamp field to time and then comparing - ``TIME (TimeStampFieldTime) = TimeField``

Comment: @tiblu, sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @dan1111 You are right.

Comment: Why are you comparing only time?  Note that this might not generate the results you expect.  Casting to time has performance and range issues - for one thing, unless you clamp seconds, you'll get few results with base equality.  You'd likely be better off constructing a set of timestamps to use...

Answer (score 0):

By the article @ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html it looks like you should get away with casting timestamp field to time and then comparing - `TIME (TimeStampFieldTime) = TimeField`

Comment: Note that this would prevent an index from being used